# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am trying to convert a String to timestamp. 
my string contains time and time zone ('05:03:05.875+02:00') but I get the following error:

**error**

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '05:03:05.875+02:00'
>   could not be parsed at index 0

**Code**

```
 String timewithZone= "05:03:05.875+02:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
final ZonedDateTime a2=ZonedDateTime.parse(timewithZone,formatter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String timewithZone = "05:03:05.875+02:00";
    OffsetTime time = OffsetTime.parse(timewithZone);
    System.out.println("Parsed into " + time);
```

This outputs

> Parsed into 05:03:05.875+02:00

Your string contains a time and an offset, but no date. This conforms nicely, neither with an `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` nor a `ZonedDateTime`, but with an `OffsetTime`, a seldom used class that I think is there exactly because such a thing sometimes occurs in XML.

There is also an `ISO_OFFSET_TIME` formatter built in, but since this is the default format for `OffsetTime` we do not need to specify it.

Comment: This is an idiomatic solution. I am wondering how it remained unnoticed for so long. Probably, it's because the usage of offset time is rare; most commonly `OffsetDateTime` is used.

Comment: It's the idiomatic solution to a problem that very few people have because its relation to real life is questionable, @ArvindKumarAvinash. So it doesn't deserve much attention.

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because your string does not have the date related tokens. Check the example in the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME). In order to make it work you will need to add year/month/day data:

```
String timewithZone= "2018-07-3T05:03:05.875+02:00";
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.
 I import the data from a dynamic xml file so I can't change or add anything. any solution?

Comment: I tried "iso_offset_time" but it throw an exception because of the seconds

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME because your date format does not adhere to that.

In fact, you don't even have a real date because there is no date component, only a time component.
You could define your own SimpleDateFormat instance with the format you're receiving, but you'll have to handle the fact that this data isn't really all that useful without date information. For example, that offset doesn't really tell us that much, because it might be in some region's Daylight Savings Time (DST) or not. And this heavily depends on on what actual DATE it is, not just what time.

You'll have to find out what the provider of this data even means with this, because right now you simply don't have enough information to really parse this into a proper date.

If this data just means a simple time stamp, used for for example saying "our worldwide office hours lunch time is at 12:30" then you could us the LocalTime class. That would be one of the few cases where a time string like this without a date is really useful. I have a sneaking suspicion this is not your scenario though.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround may be

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
String str = "05:03:05.875+02:00";
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(str, formatter);
System.out.println(time);
```

I tried the code in the format what you are getting,

Output :

> 05:03:05.875

Is this the one you are looking for?